# Changing JS mask on_focus to on_load or equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textfield

Currently, my text field will only change its appearance after clicking on it (see attached screenshot). I am trying to change it so that it appears like that all the time, without the need to click on it (the field is pre-filled with values).

Here is the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="1234567890" id="customersNumber" data-type="phone">
```

JQuery JS:

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input[data-type="phone"]', function() {
$(this).mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

[image: Input field]

Thank you.

Comment: You're using delegated event handlers, how is the element created ?

Comment: I am using the Spring framework, here is the relevant code:

'<formElement:formInputBox type="text" value="1234567890" idKey="customersNumber" datatype="phone" />'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LNtrE/